# Accessing Application object in Outlook ribbon button using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, outlook

I'm new to Visual Studio.  Trying to create an Outlook Plugin invoked from a button in a ribbon.

How do I gain access to the Outlook application object from the event handler of the button?

I tried:

`Outlook.Application application = this.Application;`

but that didn't work because *this* refers to the ribbon.  I blindly tried (after searching extensively) Parent.Application, but again, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late but would help someone in need

```
Outlook.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
```

Answer (score 1):

I facilitated an answer by instantiating an instance of the object:

```
    // declare the variable to hold the object
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app;

    // instantiate an Outlook application object
    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```